# how to added new line in java while parsing json from php mysql

Tags: java, android, json

I am parsing json from php mysql server, i want to added a new line (\n) in my java xml textview field, i am get "\n" this type of json object, i want this (\n) are replace and convert \n new line in my java code.

My json parsing class are :

```
public class ParseTeamPlayer {

    public static String[] dolName;
    public static String[] dolPhoto;
    public static String[] kheloyarTitle;
    public static String[] kheloyarSL;
    public static String[] kheloyarName;

    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "tm_pl";
    public static final String KEY_DOL = "dol";
    public static final String KEY_PHOTO = "dol_phot";
    public static final String KEY_PLYR_TITLE = "plyr_title";
    public static final String KEY_PLYR_SL = "plyr_nam1";
    public static final String KEY_PLYR_NAME = "plyr_nam";
    private JSONArray users = null;

    private String json;

    public ParseTeamPlayer(String json){
        this.json = json;
    }

    public String getJson() {
        return this.json;
    }


    protected void parseJSON(){
        JSONObject jsonObject=null;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            users = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

            //   id = new String[users.length()];
            dolName = new String[users.length()];
            dolPhoto = new String[users.length()];
            kheloyarTitle = new String[users.length()];
            kheloyarSL = new String[users.length()];
            kheloyarName = new String[users.length()];



            for(int i=0;i<users.length();i++){
                JSONObject myjsonObject = users.getJSONObject(i);

                dolName[i] = myjsonObject.getString(KEY_DOL);
                dolPhoto[i] = myjsonObject.getString(KEY_PHOTO);
                kheloyarTitle[i] = myjsonObject.getString(KEY_PLYR_TITLE);
                kheloyarSL[i] = myjsonObject.getString(KEY_PLYR_SL);
                kheloyarName[i] = myjsonObject.getString(KEY_PLYR_NAME);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output of

```
{
    "tm_pl": [{
        "id": "1",
        "dol_phot": "Amar",
        "dol": "Bangladesh",
        "plyr_title": "Player List",
        "plyr_nam1": "Sapik \n Tami \n Rahi"
     }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE` flag to your `TextView` before setting `plyr_nam1`.

```
tv.setInputType(tv.getInputType()|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```

Also try to remove spaces in **"Sapik \n Tami \n Rahi"** before and after the **"\n"** character.